# Grammar in Ruby "&&="

Tags: ruby

What does `&&=` mean in the following method?

```
records.each do |record|
  raise_on_type_mismatch!(record)
  add_to_target(record) do |rec|
    result &&= insert_record(rec, true, should_raise) unless owner.
      new_record?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a &&= b` is a short form (aka syntactic sugar) for:

```
a && a = b
```

This short form is provided for operators (including but not possibly limited to) `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `%`, `**`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `&&`, `||` (credits to @Stefan for full list of [supported operators shortcuts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment)):

```
a = 5
a += 5
#⇒ 10

a = true
a &&= true
#⇒ true
a &&= false
#⇒ false
```

`&&` is a **logical and** aka “[conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)” as opposed to `||` which is **logical or** aka “[disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).”

Comment: I'm not sure if the code example at the end is sufficiently clear. Could you describe in plain words what `&&` does as opposed to `||`?

Comment: Both, `&&` and `||` are logical operators. The binary ones are `&` and `|`.

Comment: @Stefan sure, why? Ah, I guess “boolean and” (not “binary” though) was misleading. Changed.

Comment: Actually, `a &&= b` is short for `a && a = b`, while `a ||= b` is short for `a || a = b`, like @Aetherus implied in his answer.

Comment: @SilverPhoenix Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: This evening I noticed one can write `d >>= 1`, where `d` is an instance of the class [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html).

Comment: @CarySwoveland ...and surprisingly yield a _one month after_ :)

Comment: The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment) lists `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `**`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<` and `>>` (in addition to `||` and `&&`)

Comment: `a && a = b` should be `a = a && b`. The results are the same with the logical operators, but with arithmetic operators, `a = a + b` is right and `a + a = b` is wrong.

Comment: @cozyconemotel Incorrect. Try to define your own accessor `class A; def a=(val); puts 'a='; @a = val; end; end` and you’ll see that it won’t be called on `a = A.new; a.a = false; a &&= 42`.

Answer (score 3):

It means if the previous value of `result` is `false` or `nil`, then keep it and skip further `insert_record` calls, else set the value of `result` to the return value of `insert_record`.